# ASP Page Refresh

Tags: asp-classic

I have a form in ASP. User can add new values in the input form and press Save button to save the record.On clicking the view button,the updated values aren't entered.To display the updated values, a page refresh is required.Is there a way to get the updated values without having to do a manual refresh.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Maithreyi

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript framework such as JQuery or ExtJS or just manual XmlHttpRequest to invoke a web service to obtain the value from the server side. And finally change the input control using Dhtml.

I am assuming that there is no code behind in classic ASP.

This article might help you : http://www.andrewrowland.com/article/display/consume-dot-net-web-service-with-jquery

http://elegantcode.com/2008/12/02/calling-remote-aspnet-web-services-from-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to debug this without any code, but it almost sounds like you're retrieving the data to display before the code to update the data is run. Another option is that the browser or proxy is displaying cached data. Try adding the following to the top of your page to see if the problem goes away.

```
with Response   
    .ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1
    .Expires = 0
    .CacheControl = "no-cache"
end with
```